# No reaction after clicking on li in custom context menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tampermonkey

I coded a simple context menu which appears after clicking on a `li` of an unordered list. I need an alert to show after clicking on a `li` inside of the context menu, but nothing happens.

I used the jquery function `on` (which replaced `delegate()`) since the context menu is dynamically generated during runtime:

```
$(".contextMenu").on("click", "li", function() {
    var c = $(this).attr("class");
    alert("Klassname:" + c);
});
```

But nothing happens. I am clueless now.

Please add the following script to your tampermonkey engine and try it out.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Burning Series
// @namespace    http://bs.to/
// @version      1.0
// @description  -
// @author       Me
// @match        https://bs.to/andere-serien
// @require      https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js
// @grant        GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

GM_addStyle('.contextMenuParent { position: relative;  }');
GM_addStyle('.contextMenuContainer { position: absolute; background: gray; z-index: 100; -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 31px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);-moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 31px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);}');
GM_addStyle('.contextMenu { display: grid; padding: 4px; top: 0; left: 25px; width: 200px; border: 1px solid black;  color: black; }');
GM_addStyle('.contextMenu li { border-bottom: 1px solid gray; }');
GM_addStyle('.contextMenu li:hover { cursor: pointer; color: red; }');

var contextMenuLinks =
    "<li class='contextMenu01'>A</li>"+
    "<li class='contextMenu02'>B</li>" +
    "<li class='contextMenu03'>C</li>" +
    "<li class='contextMenu04'>D</li>" +
    "<li class='contextMenu05'>E</li>" +
    "<li class='contextMenu06'>F</li>";


$(document).ready(function() {

    $("div.genre > ul > li").each(function(i, obj) {

        $(this).addClass("contextMenuParent");

        $(this).contextmenu(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $(".contextMenuContainer").remove();
            $(this).append("<div class='contextMenuContainer'><ul class='contextMenu'>" + contextMenuLinks + "</ul></div>");
        });
    });

    $(".contextMenu").on("click", "li", function() {
        var c = $(this).attr("class");
        alert("test:" + c);
    });
});
```

[Here](https://bs.to/andere-serien) is the target page.

Comment: Your code appends `<ul class='contextMenu'>` only when the context menu is invoked but `$(".contextMenu")` runs before that and finds nothing. You can delegate via `contextMenuParent` instead.

Comment: Indeed @wOxxOm use `delegate` instead of `on`

Comment: But delgate is deprecatred from jquey 3.0 http://api.jquery.com/delegate/
i think some other issue is there. Can you try adding debugger in .contextMenu event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are adding the `<li>` elements by `append()` methods, thats why the click event on `li` elements directly bounds instead of delegate, means the events will only work if the element is already present in the DOM not on dynamically created elements

So you will need to bind an **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** here with higher level element like `body` or `document`.

Try this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".contextMenu li", function() {
  var c = $(this).attr("class");
  alert("Klassname:" + c);
});
```